# How to get the topics and files of clusters in mahout?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, hdfs, data-mining, mahout

I'm new to mahout. I want to know how to get the topics of particular cluster and file names of that cluster. i.e These files are clustered into this cluster with these topics like that. I read that there is an utility ClusterDumper which will do this task. But i don't know how. Can anybody give an example to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering != Topic Modeling.

Assuming that you are talking about k-means, the cluster will give you an average word frequency vector. Turning this into a *meaningful* topic for end users is a very different and much more challenging task. **Don't assume Mahout will present you with a pretty result like "American Football"**. It can't. Nobody can do this unsupervised.

Comment: yeah i want to know how to do clustering for documents. i want to group the documents unsupervised. if i give 100 documents it should be grouped say 5 categories. Is there a way to do this in Mahout?. It should be scalable too.

Comment: I don't use Mahout. IMHO it is very slow. I don't think clustering works well, either.

Comment: In that case, for clustering large scale documents which one is the desired tool? I want to group documents which is TB in size.

Comment: I don't have TB of such documents. Not after vectorization; and raw data size doesn't matter. But in all my benchmarks, Mahout was slow. I'd start using it when I'd have a 100+ node cluster, I guess.

Comment: Why don't you just benchmark different tools on your data? Don't rely on recommendations - but benchmark!